# Kivy button text animation

Tags: python, animation, kivy

I would like to animate my buttons text in. Is there a proper way for it?

I'm using MDRaisedButtons, and my goal is to fade in and fade out the text within the buttons.

thanks

I tried animate different widgets (like MDLabel), and i was able to animate the opacity, but it did not work for the button's text.

Comment: Try animating the text `color`.

Comment: it doesn't work in case of a button

Comment: Yes it does. Please post your code.

Comment: Yes. you were right, it does work actually! Thanks!